# app store version crashes but in debug mode it is okay

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an app in app store. 
After updating my app, it crashes right after it launches. (see a black screen for less than a second and then it is like i pressed the home button.)

I tested it on my iphone attached to xcode and it is okay in debug mode.

i tested it in 5.1.0 and it is okay.

when i download it from app store it crashes.

any one had troubles with 5.1.1 ?

Comment: It's entirely possible that this is [Apple's fault](http://www.theverge.com/2012/7/4/3138007/ios-mac-apps-reportedly-crashing-corrupt-app-store-updates). Seems like they were sending our corrupt updates for a while.

Comment: Have you tried building and testing release mode(not debug)?  I have had similar crashing problems due to different linker flags between debug and release modes.

Comment: i did, its okay in both modes

Comment: as a follow up to @vcsjones comment, that is most likely what *is indeed happening* --> http://boingboing.net/2012/07/05/appstore-delivering-corrupt-up.html -- looking at the device console should tell you for sure.

Comment: unknown SpringBoard[7578] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 26545: (os/kern) failure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple acknowledges that there is a problem with the newly uploaded binaries in the AppStore. By the moment app developers are recommended to hold off on submitting applications to the App Store until this issue is resolved. Here is a [link](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=23004).